# Capture of moved value that cannot be copied

Tags: rust, kuchiki

I'm using [Kuchiki](https://github.com/SimonSapin/kuchiki) to parse some HTML and making HTTP requests using [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) to concurrently operate on results through [scoped_threadpool](https://github.com/Kimundi/scoped-threadpool-rs).

I select and iterate over listings. I decide the number of threads to allocate in the threadpool based on the number of listings:

```
let listings = document.select("table.listings").unwrap();
let mut pool = Pool::new(listings.count() as u32);
pool.scoped(|scope| {
    for listing in listings {
        do_stuff_with(listing);
    }
});
```

When I try to do this I get `capture of moved value: listings`. `listings` is `kuchiki::iter::Select<kuchiki::iter::Elements<kuchiki::iter::Descendants>>`, which is non-copyable -- so I get neither an implicit clone nor an explicit `.clone`.

Inside the pool I can just do `document.select("table.listings")` again and it will work, but this seems unnecessary to me since I already used it to get the count. I don't need `listings` after the loop either.

Is there any way for me to use a non-copyable value in a closure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, I *think* it's not possible the way you want to do it.

Your `listings.count()` consumes the iterator `listings`. You can avoid this by writing `listings.by_ref().count()`, but this won't have the desired effect, since `count()` will consume all elements of the iterator, so that the next call to `next()` will always yield `None`.

The only way to do achieve your goal is to somehow get the length of the iterator `listings` without consuming its elements. The trait [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) was built for this purpose, but it seems that [`kuchiki::iter::Select`](https://simonsapin.github.io/kuchiki/kuchiki/iter/struct.Select.html) doesn't implement it. Note that this may also be impossible for that kind of iterator.

**Edit**: As @delnan suggested, another possibility is of course to collect the iterator into a `Vec`. This has some disadvantages, but may be a good idea in your case.

---

Let me also note, that you probably shouldn't create one thread for every line in the `SELECT` result set. Usually threadpools use approximately as many threads as there are CPUs.

Comment: I tried specifically using num_cpus and making the thread pool that size but it was _much_ slower. I'm not sure how to determine the optimal thread pool size in this case. When I don't use a thread pool and just spawn a thread in the loop it works okay (and is fast) too. Any other suggestions for that?

Comment: I don't have any good suggestions, except for: measure, measure, measure. For example: are all your CPU core on full load when using `num_cpus`? You can also use twice the number of CPUs. I don't know what algorithm `scoped_threadpool` uses: maybe the work for each thread is so little that the scheduling takes most of the time... --> I don't know, sorry ;)

Comment: Is `do_stuff_with` I/O-heavy? Then it makes sense that N threads can't saturate N CPUs, and if you have beefy I/O connections they probably can't saturate your that either. However, if you might end up with thousands of `listing`s it'll probably still degrade performance to launch *that many* threads, so I'd suggest experimenting with a (possibly large) multiple of the CPU count.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Whether an exact count can be determined is really dependent on the implementation. A no-allocation streaming implementation would not be able to predict the count, as to get it requires fully parsing the document and storing all elements.

Comment: Oh and another possibility would be to `.collect()` the query result in a vector. This decreases the parallelism a bit, but memory-wise you already risk having all results in memory at once (if you keep launching one thread per listing), so that's not a concern here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh sure, you're right. I didn't even read what `kuchiki` is about and assumed it's an SQL SELECT >_< (which sometimes can tell the size of the result set)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: In any case your advice is sound, the size of the thread pool should depend on available hardware, not spawning one thread per computation is the point of using a pool.